# Contraction of a vector and an alternating tensor product of vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

In Hamilton's *Mathematical Gauge Theory* he gives the following definition.

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space with a symmetric bilinear form $Q$. For $v \in V$ and $\sigma \in \Lambda^k V$ there is a unique $(k-1)$-form $v \lrcorner \sigma \in \Lambda^{k-1}V$, called the **contraction** of $v$ and $\sigma$, with the following properties
>
> 1. if $\sigma \in V$, then $v \lrcorner = Q(v, \sigma)$;
> 2. For all $\sigma \in \Lambda^kV, \omega \in \Lambda^\ell V$ we have $$v \lrcorner(\sigma \wedge \omega) = (v \lrcorner \sigma) \wedge \omega + (-1)^k \sigma \wedge (v \lrcorner \omega).$$

I am familiar with contractions if we take $V = V^*$, in which case $\Lambda^kV^*$ is simply the set of differential forms of degree $k$. Thus it makes sense to contract this object with a vector (i.e. interior multiplication).

However the above definition is more general. An element of $\Lambda^k$ is an alternating tensor of *vectors* and not *covectors*. That is, an element of $\Lambda^k$ is of the form $v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$. These cannot take a vector as an input, so how does it make sense to contract them?

Comment: You can’t in general. In general, if you have $\sigma\in\bigwedge^k(V)$, then you’d need a $\lambda\in V^*$ in order to create the contraction $\lambda\,\lrcorner\,\sigma$. That’s why the bilinear form $Q$ is there. It takes two vectors and produces a number (i.e given $v\in V$, you apply the previous argument with $\lambda=Q(v,\cdot)$). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4770550/568204) it is written out using the usual inner product notation $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ rather than the $Q$ notation, but it works identically.

Comment: @peek-a-boo That post was very helpful and clear, thank you!